# Why I'm not getting "Multiple definition" error from the g++?

Tags: linux, linker, g++, definition

I tried to link my executable program with 2 static libraries using g++. The 2 static libraries have the same function name. I'm expecting a "multiple definition" linking error from the linker, but I did not received. Can anyone help to explain why is this so?

#### staticLibA.h

```
#ifndef _STATIC_LIBA_HEADER
#define _STATIC_LIBA_HEADER

int hello(void);

#endif
```

#### staticLibA.cpp

```
#include "staticLibA.h"

int hello(void)
{
    printf("\nI'm in staticLibA\n");
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -m32 -o staticLibA.o staticLibA.cpp                                                                             
ar -cvq ../libstaticLibA.a staticLibA.o                                                                                                                           
a - staticLibA.o
```

#### staticLibB.h

```
#ifndef _STATIC_LIBB_HEADER
#define _STATIC_LIBB_HEADER

int hello(void);

#endif
```

#### staticLibB.cpp

```
#include "staticLibB.h"

int hello(void)
{
    printf("\nI'm in staticLibB\n");
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -m32 -o staticLibB.o staticLibB.cpp 
ar -cvq ../libstaticLibB.a staticLibB.o 
a - staticLibB.o
```

#### main.cpp

```
extern int hello(void);

int main(void)
{
 hello();
 return 0;
}
```

output:

```
g++ -c  -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -o multipleLibsTest main.o  -L. -lstaticLibA -lstaticLibB -lstaticLibC -ldl -lpthread -lrt
```

Comment: What does `hello()` print when you run the program? I would assume that the linking order determines the answer. That is, `-lstaticLibA -lstaticLibB` will give a different answer from `-lstaticLibB -lstaticLibA`.

Comment: My apology. I do not how to edit my post so I posted a new question at ["How to avoid multiple definition linking error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654365/how-to-avoid-multiple-definition-linking-error)

Answer (score 1):

The linker does not look at `staticLibB`, because by the time `staticLibA` is linked, there are no unfulfilled dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

That's an easy one. An object is only pulled out of a library if the symbol referenced hasn't already been defined. Only one of the hellos are pulled (from A). You'd get errors if you linked with the .o files.

Answer (score 1):

When the linker tries to link `main.o` into `multipleLibsTest` and sees that `hello()` is unresolved, it starts searching the libraries in the order given on the command line. It will find the definition of `hello()` in `staticLibA` and will terminate the search.

It will not look in `staticLibB` or `staticLibC` at all.

If `staticLibB.o` contained another symbol not in `staticLibA` and that was pulled into the final executable, you then get a multiple definition of `hello` error, as individual `.o` files are pulled out of the library and two of them would have `hello()`. Reversing the order of `staticLibA` and `staticLibB` on the link command line would then make that error go away.