# How to avoid multiple definition linking error?

Tags: c++, linux, linker, g++, multiple-definition-error

Beside moving the `hello()` function into another source (.cpp) file or renaming the function. Is there any other methods to avoid the linking error?

**staticLibA.h**

```
#ifndef _STATIC_LIBA_HEADER
#define _STATIC_LIBA_HEADER

int hello(void);
int hello_staticLibA_only(void);

#endif
```

**staticLibA.cpp**

```
#include "staticLibA.h"

int hello(void)
{
    printf("\nI'm in staticLibA\n");
    return 0;
}

int hello_staticLibA_only(void)
{
    printf("\nstaticLibA: hello_staticLibA_only\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -m32 -o staticLibA.o staticLibA.cpp
ar -cvq ../libstaticLibA.a staticLibA.o
a - staticLibA.o
```

**staticLibB.h**

```
#ifndef _STATIC_LIBB_HEADER
#define _STATIC_LIBB_HEADER

int hello(void);
int hello_staticLibB_only(void);

#endif
```

**staticLibB.cpp**

```
#include "staticLibB.h"

int hello(void)
{
    printf("\nI'm in staticLibB\n");
    return 0;
}

int hello_staticLibB_only(void)
{
    printf("\nstaticLibB: hello_staticLibB_only\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -m32 -o staticLibB.o staticLibB.cpp 
ar -cvq ../libstaticLibB.a staticLibB.o 
a - staticLibB.o
```

**main.cpp**

```
extern int hello(void);
extern int hello_staticLibA_only(void);
extern int hello_staticLibB_only(void);

int main(void)
{
  hello();
  hello_staticLibA_only();
  hello_staticLibB_only();
  return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
g++ -c  -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -o multipleLibsTest main.o  -L. -lstaticLibA -lstaticLibB -lstaticLibC -ldl -lpthread -lrt
./libstaticLibB.a(staticLibB.o): In function `hello()':
staticLibB.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `hello()'
./libstaticLibA.a(staticLibA.o):staticLibA.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [multipleLibsTest] Error 1
```

Answer (score 11):

Since you appear to own both libraries, it's unclear why you can't rename the function...

In your `main`, you have this line:

```
hello();
```

What are you expecting to happen here, if you make the linking error go away?  Should it call the implementation in `LibA`, or `LibB`?  Relying on the order that you pass the libraries to the linker to determine which function gets linked seems like a **very bad idea**.  In a real example, what would happen if your `hello_staticLibB_only` function was calling `hello()`?  It could end up calling the version of the function that's in the other library...

As you're using `g++`, you should consider putting your library functions into a `namespace` (they're designed to help you avoid this kind of nameing conflict).  This would allow both your code and the linker to tell the difference between the methods.

Following this approach for `LibA`, you would have:

**staticLibA.h**

```
#ifndef _STATIC_LIBA_HEADER
#define _STATIC_LIBA_HEADER

// Declare namespace to keep library functions together
namespace LibA {
    int hello(void);
    int hello_staticLibA_only(void);
}

#endif
```

**staticLibA.cpp**

```
#include "staticLibA.h"
#include <stdio.h>

// Indicate that contained function definitions belong in the LibA namespace
namespace LibA {
    int hello(void)
    {
        printf("\nI'm in staticLibA\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int hello_staticLibA_only(void)
    {
        printf("\nstaticLibA: hello_staticLibA_only\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
// These declarations would usually be in a header... but I've left
// them here to match your sample code...

// declare relevant functions to belong to the LibA namespace
namespace LibA{
    extern int hello(void);
    extern int hello_staticLibA_only(void);
}

// declare relevant functions from LibB (note they are not
// in a namespace)
extern int hello(void);
extern int hello_staticLibB_only(void);

int main(void)
{
    // Explicitly call the hello from LibA
    LibA::hello();
    // Call the other library function (also from LibA)
    LibA::hello_staticLibA_only();

    // Call library functions from LibB (note they don't require a namespace
    // because I haven't updated it to have one)
    hello();
    hello_staticLibB_only();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The linking error specifically refers to hello.  This shows up because both libraries provide definitions of "hello".  There is no other linking error here.

You can either put hello in a separate library, have hello reside in a separate library, or just have the executable link against a hello object file [hello.o]